Adding exemptions in Firebase automatic indexing
I'm storing data in firebase with this structure:
/aggregate_data/{user id}/{product id}/data
The aggregate_data collection is the root collection ID and the rest subcollections and documents under it except data are dynamically generated. The data stored under data document is a map with a structure:
{
  'YYYYMMDD': {
     'field1': value1,
     'field2': value2,
     'field3': value3,
     'field4': value4,

  },
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  'YYYYMMDD': {
     'field1': value1,
     'field2': value2,
     'field3': value3,
     'field4': value4,

  },

}

The data inside this data document has now reached a point where it's not allowing me to add (update) more data in this map since it's being auto-indexed by Firebase and this error is produced as a result:
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 too many index entries for entity

I tried adding an exception in indexing to prevent indexing on this document so that I can add more data but not sure if I'm doing it the right way. So far I've tried the combinations shown in this screenshot:

Where sessions is one of the fields nested inside the map. Please note that the map keys YYYYMMDD are dynamically generated and contain date strings. What would be the right Collection ID & Field path combinations needed for me to stop the indexing so that I can add more data?

Seemed to be any easy one since the subcollection in my case was a dynamic one I used the * wildcard as Collection ID and the field names field1, field2 etc. were known so I had to add them specifically to prevent them from being auto-indexed and this fixed the issue. One such example is given below for field name sessions:



The data stored under data document is a map with this structure.

As far as I understand the data field is a Map that contains in terms other Map objects containing multiple fields. This looks good at first glance.

The data inside this data document has now reached a point where it's not allowing me to add (update) more data in this map since it's being auto-indexed by Firebase and this error is produced as a result:


google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 too many index entries for entity


As far as I can see in the official documentation regarding usage and limits in Firestore, the maximum number of index entries for each document is 40,000 and not 400.

I tried adding an exception in indexing to prevent indexing on this document so that I can add more data but not sure if I'm doing it the right way.

Even if you can manage the indexes somehow to stay below this limitation, there is another limitation that you should care about. So bear in mind that you're also limited to how much data you can put into a document. According to the same docs:

The maximum size for a document: 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)

As you can see, you are limited to 1 MiB total of data in a single document. When we are talking about storing text, you can store pretty much but as your documents get bigger, be careful about this limitation too.
So storing large amounts of data into a single document might not be the best option in your cause. So I recommend you split that data into separate documents rather than nesting it into a single document. In this way, you won't reach those limitations and you'll be able to query the documents in any way you want.

I very well understand that there are limitations in terms of size, I intend to change the structure in the future altogether. Also, 400 in the error above is an error code and not the maximum number of index entries. Futhermore the structure is as follows: aggregate_data(collection)->user_id(document)->product_id(sub-collection)->data(document), the map given above is stored under data document. What should be the combination I should use to prevent it from being indexed?

Oh ok, it's the error code, but it refers to the maximum number of indexes. You can indeed use single-field index exemptions, but I don't recommend that since you can reach the 1 MiB limitation in the same way.

I am trying to use the single-field index exemptions, but how do I add those? Since the collection name generated in my case (product id) under which the data is stored is a dynamic one, so ideally I don't have the sub collection id beforehand. How do I achieve this?

I have just seen your answer, which will solve the problem of single-field index exemptions.

So did my answer/comments help? Can I help you with other information?

Thanks for offering the help Alex. My problem is solved as of now, don't need any other help for now!
